# using assembly in qt

Tags: qt, assembly

Is there any way to use assembly language inside Qt projects?

Comment: What compiler and environment you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, however its not dependent on Qt as much as its dependent on the underlying compiler.

GCC has great [inline assembly support.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) MSVC++ also has [inline assembly support.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx)

You are of course not limited to inline assembly, you can also do assembly in an outside file and link it into your project. This is again compiler/assembler/linker dependent.